# Error: Invalid: Unrecognized filesystem type in URI when loading parquet file from url using arrow package

Tags: r, parquet, apache-arrow

I'm pretty new to parquet file format and I'm using the `read_parquet()` (in the `arrow` package) to load parquet file (stored in my Dropbox share folder) into R. However, I received the following error message

```css
library(arrow)
 df <- read_parquet("https://www.dropbox.com/s/mysgf4sojpjgyp7/part-394.parquet?dl=1")

Error: Invalid: Unrecognized filesystem type in URI: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mysgf4sojpjgyp7/part-394.parquet?dl=1
```

What might cause this problem here and do I need to partition the url link beforehand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file reading functions in the `arrow` package do not yet support `HTTP[S]` URIs. We hope to add this feature in a future release ([ARROW-7594](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-7594)). In the meantime:

If you have Dropbox installed on the computer where you're running this, use the local path to the file instead of the `HTTPS` URI.

If you do not have Dropbox installed, then download the file first, like this:

```r
myfile <- tempfile()
download.file(
  "https://www.dropbox.com/s/mysgf4sojpjgyp7/part-394.parquet?dl=1",
  myfile,
  mode = "wb"
)
df <- read_parquet(myfile)
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. But I received yet another error message after running your code, its says `Error: IOError: Couldn't deserialize thrift: don't know what type:`

Comment: If you're using Windows, you'll need to use `mode = "wb"` in the call to `download.file()`. I updated the answer to use this.

Comment: Yes, I'm using windows, and after I add this additional argument, the code works. Thanks so much for your help.